# How to overcome of passing single static value to the function?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm displaying as many buttons as the number of rows in query. Every row has it's own names & properties. When i click on any of the buttons, it should pass that particular value to the function. But, when i tried with the following code, it only passes very first value if i click on any buttons.

```
<?php  
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  
        echo "<figure>";
        echo "<button onclick='change()' title='".$rec["UserName"]."' class='fa fa-user' id='myButton1' value='".$rec["UserName"]."' style='font-size:100px;color:red'></button>";
        echo "<figcaption>".$rec["UserName"]."</figcaption>";
        echo "</figure>";
        //echo "</a>";
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{   
    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    alert(elem.value);    
    // SQL Query and display the results in a proper table <?php echo "<table><tr><td>".elem.value."</td></tr></table>"; ?>   
}  
</script>
```

How do make it passing dynamic values (clicking upon any buttons, it should pass it's corresponding value) ?

Comment: Your id is hardcoded to "myButton1"

Comment: @Marinus : Yeah. But corresponding value will be different, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<figure>";
        echo "<button onclick='change(this.value)' title='".$rec["UserName"]."' class='fa fa-user' id='myButton1' value='".$rec["UserName"]."' style='font-size:100px;color:red'></button>";
        echo "<figcaption>".$rec["UserName"]."</figcaption>";
        echo "</figure>";
        //echo "</a>";
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change(button_val)
{
    alert(button_val);
    // SQL Query and display the results in a proper table <?php echo "<table><tr><td>".button_val."</td></tr></table>"; ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Copy sample code over here and try to integrate
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="change(this.value);"  value="Test Value" style='font-size:100px;color:red'>Ok</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(button_val){
    alert(button_val);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks Jignesh. Both seems to be same solution, the difference is way of passing and accessing it. passing as 'this' and accessing as 'btn.value' and in other case passing as 'this.value' and accessing as 'btn'. In between, how to pass more than one parameter ?

Comment: How to pass more than one parameter ? onclick='change(this.value,?,?,?)'

Answer (score 2):

**`id` values must be unique in HTML.** Having multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid and will not work as desired.

You don't need `id`s at all. Instead, the minimal change is to pass `this` into your function:

```
<button onclick='change(this)' ... >
```

and in your function

```
function change(btn) {
    alert(btn.value);
}
```

But the real answer is *don't use `onclick` attribute event handlers*. They're a mid-1990's technology. Things have moved on in 20 years.

In this case, I'd use a delegated handler on the container all these figures are in. There's probably a container nearer to them that you can use, but in the worst case, you can use `document.body`:

Put a common identifying feature on the buttons (say, a `class`), then:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".the-class", function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

One handler handles all the buttons, since `click` bubbles.

Again you probably want a container closer to the list of figures, rather than `document.body`.

Comment: First method worked fine !!!, Thank u. I'll try second method as well. Instead of alerting, if i want to query to DB and then display the result in a table. How would i do that ?

Comment: @User: That's a completely different (and very broad) question. Basically, you'll use ajax to send the request to the server, and then do the DB query in PHP.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I'll try it out. What if multiple values to be passed out the function ?